# Ubuntu windows no longer display menubar, not draggable

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I just moved onto Ubuntu for my "experimental" development, using RoR and Aptana. I have an installation of Ubuntu sitting alongside my Windows 7 installation.

At some point over the last week or so, I did something, I know not what, and I'm now in a situation where all the windows on my Ubuntu desktop refuse to display menubars. I now can't drag my windows around anywhere, it's a real headwrecker. It's not stopping me getting work done, but it's just annoying that I can't drag windows around as I see fit.

Anyone know how this can be counteracted? Or how it might have happened in the first place?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu is it? What desktop and/or window manager you've been using?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your window manager has died. It's job is to draw window decorations like window title bar and borders which you can drag to move or resize window.

I guess you might be using `compiz` as your window manager. You could try running it from command line. If you will run it not from the same X11 session where you need it restored you will need to set `DISPLAY` environment variable to proper value (e.g. `:0.0`).

If that does not help you may still try other more stable manager like `metacity`.